# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/firebase'.I get this error. I have the import code for firebase in the src folder in firebase.js. Ideas?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase version @8.2.3 and I have implemented the following code in my firebase.js file

```
`import firebase from 'firebase/app';


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAnOnkuFcpOr3e05H82hPR3bzyamwJov1U",
    authDomain: "recipesapps2.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "recipesapps2",
    storageBucket: "recipesapps2.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "23528342109",
    appId: "1:23528342109:web:51e24b8fbfbacbec5c43b4"
};



if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export default firebase;

export const auth = firebase.auth();`
```

in the src folder(freely alongside App.js,App.css and so on), but it keeps giving me this error

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/firebase'.
Any suggestions....I want to import it in my src/components/Authentication/Login folder in my Login.js file

Comment: Showing the failing import statement would help.

Comment: That's the import line i tried "import {auth} from './src/firebase';" in my component file, which in the src/components/Authentication/Login/Login.js

Comment: Don't know much about react, but the leading dot make this path relative: Login.js and firebase.js are supposed in the same directory. Try `import ... from /src/firebase`

Comment: Or follow the path upwards: `... from ../../../firebase`